# Force a link in I.E. to open in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have two links in a corporate intranet site, built in Sharepoint, that I need to link to Firefox.  The links are to an external site that does not work in I.E.  However, the corporate browser is I.E., so that's what most people see.

I found the below code that works when I have one link.  How do I get it to work for two links?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>HTA Test</title>
<hta:application applicationname="HTA Test" scroll="yes"     singleinstance="yes">
<script type="text/javascript">
function openURL()
{
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Open Google">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like you would pass in the link.... I am surprised the corp rules don;t have ActiveX disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your script to something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openURL(url)
{
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run(url);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="openURL('http://www.google.com')" value="Open Google">
<input type="button" onclick="openURL('http://www.yahoo.com')" value="Open Yahoo">
```